# How to to remove these (') and ('') in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm having a problem with (') and (") in Python. I wrote this code:

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import os
import numpy as np

# STEP1 Load the classic4 dataset
fold = os.path.join('classic')

corpus = []
for file in os.listdir(fold):
with open(os.path.join(fold, file)) as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.strip()
    text = text.replace('\n',' ')
    corpus.append(text)
    #print(text)

with open('terms.txt') as f:
voc = f.readlines()
voc = [v.replace('\n', '') for v in voc]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=voc)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()
#print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
#np.save('X.npy', X)
np.savetxt('X.txt', X, fmt="%d")

print(X.shape)

#  STEP2  list of lists aka tfidf_vectorized_list

with open('docbyterm.tfidf.txt') as f:
txt = f.readlines()

data = []
for i in range(7095):
data.append([])
for i in txt:
i_list = i.split(' ')
data[int(i_list[0])-1].append(int(i_list[1]))

with open('tfidf_vectorized_list.txt','w+') as f:
for i in data:
    f.write(str(i)[1:-1])
    f.write('\n')
 #print(data)

 tfidf_vectorized_list = []
 with open('tfidf_vectorized_list.txt') as f:
 for line in f:
    inner_list = []
    for elt in line.split(','):
        stripped_elt = elt.strip()
        if len(stripped_elt) > 0:
            inner_list.append(int(stripped_elt))
    tfidf_vectorized_list.append(inner_list)
 tfidf_vectorized_list = np.array(tfidf_vectorized_list)
 print(tfidf_vectorized_list)
```

The link for tfidf_vectorized_list is https://github.com/Diallosky/tfidf_vectorized_list. I noticed that my tfidf_vectorized_list is like this:

```
2, 5, 4, 1, 3
11, 7, 9, 8, 10, 6
16, 12, 14, 13, 15
11, 19, 18, 17, 15
7, 21, 20
11, 23, 22
...
23, 58, 55, 51, 53, 59, 57, 60, 50, 56, 31, 12, 54, 52
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
[['2, 5, 4, 1, 3' '']
['11, 7, 9, 8, 10, 6' '']
['16, 12, 14, 13, 15' '']
...
['23, 58, 55, 51, 53, 59, 57, 60, 50, 56, 31, 12, 54, 52' '']
```

I would like to remove the `'` and `''` characters in order to get a result like this:

```
[[2, 5, 4, 1, 3]
[11, 7, 9, 8, 10, 6]
[16, 12, 14, 13, 15]
...
[23, 58, 55, 51, 53, 59, 57, 60, 50, 56, 31, 12, 54, 52]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong in this line:

```
inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split('\n')]
```

You should split by `,` not `\n`. The statement `for line in f` automatically split the file into lines for you.

Also, if you want the output list items to be numbers, not strings, you should convert them using `int()` for example. You need to take care of empty elements because they will cause errors when using `int()` on them.

You can achieve what you want by replacing this line:

```
inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split('\n')]
```

by

```
inner_list = []
for elt in line.split(','):
    stripped_elt = elt.strip()
    if len(stripped_elt) > 0:
        inner_list.append(int(stripped_elt))
```

Comment: I tried your solution "inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]" and got some errors like: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saned/Desktop/TS_SS@Arash/TS_SS.py.py", line 56, in <module>
    inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]
  File "C:/Users/saned/Desktop/TS_SS@Arash/TS_SS.py.py", line 56, in <listcomp>
    inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I tried the code and it works without any problems. Can you post the exact code you are using with the exact contents of `tfidf_vectorized_list.txt`? If you don't want to convert items to numbers, you can remove `int()`

Comment: I also tried with "inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split(', ')]" However this time I got : [list(['2', '5', '4', '1', '3']) list(['11', '7', '9', '8', '10', '6'])
 list(['16', '12', '14', '13', '15']) ...
 list(['345', '4928', '5154', '679', '489', '5880', '727', '3811', '325', '293', '5084', '1363', '1252', '276', '4777', '2651', '4059', '479', '666', '1595', '1465', '5389', '5221', '759', '790', '2339', '5670', '4676', '1340', '5647', '740', '5581', '631', 

..... which is not the expected result I want and still have the (')

Comment: The error you are getting when using `int()` indicates that there is a non-numeric value in your data. For example, one line of your data in `tfidf_vectorized_list.txt` might be `2, 3, 5, xyz`. Here, `xyz` will cause the error. So, does your data contain non-numeric values? If so, we can find another solution

Comment: Ok. The problem was with empty elements. See the edit and check if this is what you wanted

Comment: I checked my data doesn't have non-numeric values. I uploaded the data and the code in GitHub page https://github.com/Diallosky/tfidf_vectorized_list

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. You solved my Problem1. all these (') and ('') have been removed. Now I need all the list to have the same length as described in Problem2

Comment: I think you need to put your second part as a new question. It's not related to the first part. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct and upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: How about: `inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',') if elt.strip()]`?